# node + react app build on heroku doesn't end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I am trying to start working with node. When I deploy, I run my build script which is like this:

```
"build": "cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd .. && node ./bin/www"
```

My node app is created by express generator and client is created with create-react-app. 
The idea behind the script is to move to client folder, build it with react-scripts, then back and start the server. I think I made a mistake somewhere

But the build progress stops at the end of client's build script when normally in console at that point script ended working. How do I fix this?

I don't get any errors in heroku build log until it reaches timeout. I also added react buildpack

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment - This might help

Comment: It didn't help. I am trying to understand why my build command hangs at the end of npm run build

Answer (score 1):

I created a heroku-specific script

```
"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
```

It solves my issue. Only problem is that I will need to find a new solution if I change the hosting, but for now it serves well.

Comment: don't you also have to start the express server in build, or heroku does that automatically?

Comment: It is postbuild script which is launched after build script. My build script builds and runs the express server and postbuild builds frontend